# how do I uninstall chrome OS with only my chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, playonlinux, chromebook, chromeos

I've been trying to get any linux for a while now but chrome OS keeps blocking it, I really just want to access the games on linux/ubuntu but I can't because of chrome OS. can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu -- Just a heads-up that you have this question tagged with *windows-subsystem-for-linux`, but your question does not mention anything about Windows.  I've submitted an edit removing that tag, but if you really do have a question about Windows Subsystem for Linux, please edit the question to add it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial for this here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#6-conclusion. Please note the following warning on the first page:

> **crouton is not part of the Ubuntu project** 
> While we love the value that crouton provides, please note that crouton is a third-party script. It is not provided by nor supported by Canonical nor by the Ubuntu project. Updates to Chrome OS may also make Ubuntu installations inaccessible, as has happened in the past. Use of crouton is at your own risk.

If this is a school or work computer, you should get approval from your administrator to do this, and if this is a personal computer, make sure you are aware of and accept the risks of using third-party software.